# .htacces Removes Page Styling

Tags: css, .htaccess

I'm trying to figure out how .htacces RewriteRule works.

Here is my url with fiddling about with .htacces:

```
http://mysite.nl/gve/home
```

This was:

```
http://mysite.nl/gve/index.php?p=1
```

What I'm trying to achieve is that any path in the "gve" subdirectory is redirected to the "gve/index.php" page.

I've gotten the above to work.

The next thing I would like to achieve is that the above will work when it's moved to the root direcotry of the site.

I've tried the following:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/index gve/index.php [NC,L]
```

But this seems to remove all the styling from my page. As shown below.

Here is the url:

```
http://mysite.nl/asdf/index
```

[image: http://prntscr.com/aczxje]

Why does this happen and how can I fix it?

Edit: CSS links

```
    <!-- BEGIN THEME STYLES -->
    <link href="assets/base/css/plugins.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="assets/base/css/components.css" id="style_components" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="assets/base/css/themes/custom_theme.css" rel="stylesheet" id="style_theme" type="text/css" />
    <link href="assets/base/css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <!-- END THEME STYLES -->
```

Edit 2:
My directory structure:
[image]

Comment: What's your path for the CSS file? Have you tried setting a Base href?

Comment: I've edited the question, does that answer yours? And what do you mean by base href?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base

Comment: What @AndyHolmes says is that your css links are relative : `assets/base/css/plugins.css`.  

If that works fine one the index page of your site, it will not work on urls that are not on the same level.  

You can use the `base` tag to solve this, or use an absolute path to access your assets `/assets/base/css/plugins.css`.

Comment: Thank you @damienc, that helped me alot. It works now!

Answer (score 0):

Just include this line in `.htaccess`, like

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(?:css|js)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/index gve/index.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: "cntrl" + "f5" huh ?